# How do memcache deployments on Kubernetes handle changing pod IP addresses?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, memcached

I'm trying to understand official recommendations I've found for sharded memcache deployments on Kubernetes, such as [Google's Deploying Memcached on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/deploying-memcached-on-kubernetes-engine). Specifically, where it recommends deploying a memcached Helm chart with a headless service and StatesfulSet controller so the IP address for each memcached pod can be discovered by memcached clients using DNS:

"Service discovery logic.
At a high level, the service discovery logic consists of the following steps:

1. The application queries kube-dns for the DNS record of mycache-memcached.default.svc.cluster.local.
2. The application retrieves the IP addresses associated with that record.
3. The application instantiates a new Memcached client and provides it with the retrieved IP addresses.
4. The Memcached client's integrated load balancer connects to the Memcached servers at the given IP addresses."

These steps make sense for getting the system running initially, but they don't mesh with my general understanding of treating Kubernetes pods and their IP addresses as ephemeral, including when using a StatefulSet controller. Doesn't any implementation like this, where a Kubernetes pod is hitting another Kubernetes pod via a direct IP address, require some sort of recurring service discovery mechanism to keep memcached server pod IP addresses up to date as pods are recreated over their lifetime? Without even worrying about purposefully adding/removing memcached server pods.

(The linked tutorial does continue with setting up https://github.com/facebook/mcrouter for proxying, but as far as I can that doesn't deal with the changing pod IP address issue)

I also see in official [Kubernetes Stateful Set docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/):
"The Pods' ordinals, hostnames, SRV records, and A record names have not changed, but the IP addresses associated with the Pods may have changed. In the cluster used for this tutorial, they have. This is why it is important not to configure other applications to connect to Pods in a StatefulSet by IP address."

This seems to clash directly with the Google recommendation - am I missing some key understanding?